# React-router No funciona cuando la app esta desplegada

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, react-router-dom

He desplegado una app sólo con front-end creada con *create-react-app*, en local-desarrollo funciona bien pero desplegada sólo carga la página principal.

Primero usé *Netlify* para desplegarla, cada vez que pulso cualquier link que me lleva a alguna ruta, aparece un error (`404`). Sin embargo, desplegada en el servicio *aws-amplify* no aparece el error pero la ruta siempre aparece como *"www.nombredeldominio.com/index.html"*. Es decir, cualquier ruta la entiende como `index.html`
Para el error 4040 de Netlify añadí lo siguiente en una ruta y tampoco funcionó:

```
path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/login"}
```

También he probado a añadir al *package.json* lo siguiente, que supuestamente "deja a Create React App inferir correctamente la ruta raíz para usar el archivo HTML". Pero entonces da fallo al desplegar.

```
"homepage": "https://naughty-morse-42316d6.netlify.app"
```

Así están las rutas:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  
  render(){
    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
        <Route path="/" render={(props) => <TheNavbar authentication={authProps} {...props} />} />
          <Switch>
            <News exact path="/news" />
            <AddSite exact path="/addsite" authentication={authProps} />
            <UserGallery exact path="/usergallery" />
            <Route path="/usergallery/:gallery_name" render={(props) => <EditGallery {...props} />} />
            <Home exact path="/" authentication={authProps} />
            <AboutLanding exact path="/about" />
            <Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/login"} render={(props) => <Login authentication={authProps} {...props} />} />
            <Register exact path="/register" />
            <Contact exact path="/contact" />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        
      </div>
    );
  } 
}

export default App;
```

Generalmente suelo usar el siguiente código cuando uso back-end con react pero me gustaría saber si se puede solucionar esto sin tener que añadir servidor Express/Node. :

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: necesitas añadir lo de node. En la [documentación](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) de create-react-app indican que puedes instalar el paquete `serve`.

Comment: @hawks Lo he probado pero lo único que hace es servir la app en un puerto determinado ¿?

Comment: pues habré interpretado mal la documentación quizá hay que especificar algo más. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netlify propone una solución para este error y es crear un fichero llamado `_redirects`(sin extensión) en tu carpeta `build`.

Y dentro del fichero `_redirects` poner la ruta de fallback a tu fichero `index.html`.

```
/*    /index.html  200
```

Aquí tienes más [info](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-react-application-to-netlify-363b8a98a985/)